# HTML tag charecters "<", ">" is converting into "&lt", "&gt" inside custom plugin wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress

I am using a custom registration plugin with custom email **template** which can customized from admin side. For dynamic variables to put while trigger email, I have put [USER_NAME], [USER_PWD] in email template. But for the HTML tags, Characters like "<", ">" getting replaced by &lt, &gt. Which is causing problem.

Please note that the WordPress editor is being loaded from the custom plugin.

Inside custom plugin file I am loading the editor like below;

add_settings_field(

```
        'email_field_body', 
        // use $args' label_for to populate the id inside the callback
        __('Email Body', 'email'), 
        array($this, 'email_field_body'), 
        'email', 
        'email_section_developers', 
        [
            'label_for' => 'email_field_body',
            'class' => 'email_row',
            'email_custom_data' => 'custom',
        ]

    );


function email_field_body($args) {
        wp_editor( isset( $this->options['email_field_body'] ) ? 
        esc_attr( $this->options['email_field_body']) : '' ,
        'email_field_body', $settings =
        array('textarea_name'=>"registration_email[email_field_body]") ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hade the same problem...
this comes by wordpress editor filters.
for updating the option use:

```
update_option( 'email_field_body', wp_kses_post( stripslashes ( $yourVariable ) ) );
```

Here is the documentation of the [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post)